# Link a JIRA cloud with local bitbucket server + jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jira, bitbucket

We would like to have an online "JIRA Cloud" account, linked to a local "on server" Bitbucket install. Our IT will not open any port TO bitbucket(but is ok, to allow bitbucket communicate to JIRA cloud.

I was wondering if this scenario was possible, and if there was some limitation.

Also, we will soon have a local JENKINS server. I'm not fully aware on how it integrate with JIRA, but I was told it is supposed to give indication on the current tests status, per userstories-requirement. Is this possible? Or again is it JIRA that needs to talk to JENKINS?

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a solution for linking "Jira Cloud" to a local Bitbucket?

Comment: @KarlGlennon I found something over atlassian website, but it was implying that we open our network to a very big range of IP addresses(they are hosting this in the cloud, so you're not sure that all IP are the ones from atlassian).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 12 months late, but I just connected my internal Bitbucket Server to my JIRA Cloud service using the instructions from these pages:

- https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiracloud/using-applinks-to-link-to-other-applications-779295829.html
- https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/proxying-and-securing-bitbucket-server-776640099.html

Please note that I exposed the private Bitbucket Server to the public Internet  with an existing public facing web server running Microsoft IIS 8 and the URL rewrite object.  It was quite easy to do.

If you are using IIS and rewrite rules, then don't forget to change the filtered extension list as per this Atlassian page: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/iis-http-error-404-for-cs-and-config-files-808622176.html otherwise IIS will not allow the viewing of files in the repository.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: The question was "I was wondering if this scenario was possible, and if there was some limitation" which are answered by Atlassian itself with the two links.  The question wasn't asking for explicit details.